# unknown command 'boota' try 'help' - error while booting u-boot image

Tags: u-boot, imx6

I am a beginner in u-boot. I am trying to boot Sabre SD imx6Quad board. I build u-boot source code to get u-boot-imx6qp.imx. Then I flashed the required images using MFGTools and tried booting the board from SD Card. I am getting this error:

> Unknown Command 'boota' try 'help'.

Comment: What does `help` give you?

Comment: RTM: https://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/Manual

Comment: @sawdust I referred the manual u mentioned but could not able to resolve the problem.

Comment: Apparently the **boota** command seems to be only available in a custom version of U-Boot for Android.  The error message you're seeing indicates that your build, if it is a version of U-Boot that supports **boota**, is not even configured to make it available.  E.G. see https://community.nxp.com/thread/443906